# Plotly surface plot with unequal length x and y axes

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I have a `10x12` array that I would like to plot using `plotly`. The length of x-axis is 10 and y-axis is 12. I expect the plot to have a range of 10 in the x-axis and 12 in the `y-axis`. But that is not the case. I get 10 on both axes. I have included a MWE to reproduce the issue.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data_array = np.empty((10, 12))
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(12):
        data_array[i, j] = i+j

x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
y = np.linspace(1, 12, 12)

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=data_array, x=x, y=y)])
fig.show()
```

The plot that it generates is [image]

I have tried setting the `range` via `update_layout` which doesn't solve the problem.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data_array = np.empty((10, 12))
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(12):
        data_array[i, j] = i+j

x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
y = np.linspace(1, 12, 12)

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=data_array, x=x, y=y)])
fig.update_layout(scene=dict(xaxis=dict(range=[0, 10]),
                             yaxis=dict(range=[0, 12])))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Although the range of y-axis in now till 12, there is nothing plotted in that part of the graph.
How can I get this to work? Thanks.

Based on the answer below, I have changed the code.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data_array = np.empty((10, 12))
for idx1, i in enumerate(range(0, 50, 5)):
    for idx2, j in enumerate(range(0, 24, 2)):
        data_array[idx1, idx2] = (i+j) / (50+24)

x = np.linspace(0, 45, 10)
y = np.linspace(0, 22, 12)

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=data_array.T)])
fig.show()
```

But the axes now have no correspondence with the actual x and y values. The values in the plot go from 0 to 9 and 0 to 11 for x and y axes respectively. How do I set the calibration? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix `data_array` should be transposed (x along columns, y along rows). The limit can be explicitly set by passing the `x`, `y` arguments. The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data_array = np.empty((10, 12))
for idx1, i in enumerate(range(0, 50, 5)):
    for idx2, j in enumerate(range(0, 24, 2)):
        data_array[idx1, idx2] = (i+j) / (50+24)

x = np.linspace(0, 45, 10)
y = np.linspace(0, 22, 12)

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=data_array.T, x=x, y=y)])
fig.show()
```

I am currently unable to save the image with the tag on the last position. The image obtained is as follows:

[image]

Documentation: https://plotly.com/python/3d-surface-plots/

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. My data doesn't have 1-1 correspondence with whole numbers. In other words, the x-axis value for each point rises by 5 and y axis by 2. That is `x=np.linspace(1, 50, 10)` and `y=np.linspace(1, 24, 12)`. How do I get this to reflect in the axes of the plot?

Comment: To further clear the above comment, I have added another piece of code to my question at the very end.

Comment: I had missed that part initially. I have modified my answer to support varying step size. Hope it helps :)