# Plotly 3D Surface Cutting Out Data

Tags: python, plotly-python

I tried this code with Plotly 5.10.0:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = np.arange(0.5, 1.525, 0.025)

np.random.seed(56)
z = np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.5, size=(len(x), len(y)))

fig = go.Figure(go.Surface(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    z=z)
)
fig.show()
```

The `y` values in the data should range up to `1.5`, but in the resulting plot the y axis values cut off at `0.725`:

[image: plot with y axis cut off]

Why does this occur? I can't find anything in the docs or provided examples that explains the result.

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.5, size=(len(x), len(y))))` and `df.values` is kinda pointless as you could just do `z = np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.5, size=(len(x), len(y)))`. That said, I can repro this and it's not clear where it comes from at first scan. It just helps you to remove the `pandas` noise from the problem

Comment: Hi. Thanks for looking. I am using much larger datasets that I ingest from SQL via pandas, so kept kept that in there as it is part of the work flow. I do not believe pandas is the problem though.

Comment: Sure, it just makes it easier to test for other people. There might be people who look at it and think "well, it's pandas involved, so I will probably skip it" when it isn't true. Your MCVE is perfectly adequate without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64735623/plotly-surface-plot-with-unequal-length-x-and-y-axes). If you use the transpose of Z it should work.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = np.arange(0.5, 1.525, 0.025)

np.random.seed(56)
z = np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.5, size=(len(x), len(y)))

fig = go.Figure(go.Surface(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    z=z.T)
)

fig.show()
```

On your original script, `x` has 10 elements so only the first 10 elements of `y` were being used by `go.Surface`.